# Cant delete clones of prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2d box collider which is set to `isTrigger` true and I added this script to it, which is trying to delete anything that has the tag of cookies that touches it. I can't get it to work.

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoxCookieDeleterC : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag.Equals("cookies"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);`
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You're looking for [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)

The 2D and 3D physics engines are completely and utter unrelated. You have to use the appropriate MonoBehaviour methods.

Comment: Thank you, i was going crazy but it was so simple. I watched like 5 tutorials on this but they were all on 3d unity. Thanks